# std::map find doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, std

std::map.find() is intended to return an map::iterator to an element it found if there is some or to the end() if not. I get BadPtr returned to me. The exactly same construct works fine in the other part of code. What is this?

```
class OntologyContainer {
    map<string, OntologyClass*> data;
    OntologyClass* last_added;
public:
    class iterator : public std::iterator<bidirectional_iterator_tag, OntologyClass> {
        map<string, OntologyClass*>::iterator itr;
    public:
        iterator(map<string, OntologyClass*>::iterator it) : itr(it) { }

    ...
    }

    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(data.begin());
    }

    iterator end() {
        return iterator(data.end());
    }

    iterator Find(const string & to_find) {
        map<string, OntologyClass*>::iterator it = data.find(to_find);
        // this is where it fails
        return iterator(it);
    }
```

map::iterator is wrapped for the sake of making operators * and -> returning OntologyClass objects and pointers respectively:

```
            OntologyClass& operator* () {
        return *(itr->second);
    }

    OntologyClass* operator->() {
        return itr->second;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be something to do with the fact that you inherit from `std::iterator<bidirectional_iterator_tag, OntologyClass>`, making your iterator value_type to be `OntologyClass`, rather than a *pointer* to `OntologyClass`, which is what your map iterator uses.  How are you implementing the dereference operator?

Comment: Yup, I would even suggest using `map<string, OntologyClass*>::iterator`

Comment: Yeah, it would be easier to just return a map iterator, rather than wrapping the map iterator in your own iterator class.

Comment: 1. your note about value type is absolutely right, thank you
2. i have a map of <string, OntologyClass*> pair inside to search OntologyClass objects. i needed an iterator with * and -> operators returning OntologyClass objects (pointers), so i've wrapped standard map<string, OntologyClass*>::iterator. That is why i have it as a member variable.

Comment: i've added implementation of the dereference operator to the body of the post

Comment: martinthenext, since your iterator is returning `OntologyClass&` from `operator*`, its value type is `OntologyClass`, not a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use boost I suggest using boost::transform_iterator.

This stack overflow answer has a decent example on how to do that:
[iterator adapter to iterate just the values in a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259240/iterator-adapter-to-iterate-just-the-values-in-a-map)