# iterating over a std::map using boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, stl, dictionary, bind

I have made a small example in order to understand how `boost::bind ()` works with collections. I have a class called Data:

```
class Data
{
public:
    void print ();
    const std::string& get () const;
    std::string& get () ;
};
```

I have created a `std::vector` of Data objects called samples and I am able to use `bind` in the same way as `std::mem_fun_ref` works.

```
std::for_each (samples.begin (),samples.end (),std::mem_fun_ref (&Data::print));
std::for_each (samples.begin (),samples.end (),boost::bind (&Data::print,_1));
```

The basic idea is that the `bind` returns a function object of type `bind_t<RetType=void, ObjType=Data, ArgType=void>`. The member function as the first parameter allows the compiler to deduce `RetType`, `ObjType` and `ArgType`. The placeholder `_1` corresponds to the data object which must be provided by the algorithm.

Then `std::for_each` calls the function object "for each" element in the following way:

```
for ( ; first!=last; ++first ) f(*first);
```

`bind_t::operator(ObjType& obj)` is invoked and its definition should be something like this:

```
return (obj.*_method ());
```

I have crated a class called `Filter` that performs some processing over a data element.

```
class Filter
{
    void filter (Data& data);
    ...
};
```

If I want to apply the filter over the data elements in the vector I call `bind` in the following way:

```
std::for_each (samples.begin (),samples.end (),boost::bind (&Filter::filter,filter,_1));
```

`for_each` passes a `Data` object to `bind_t::operator()`. In this case the function object already has the object and just need the parameter so in this case placeholder _1 refers to the argument.

**Here comes my question:**

How can use `bind` if I have to iterate over a `std::map` rather than a vector?

(Sorry for all the explanation, I just want to make sure that I understand the way in which `bind` works)

Comment: Summarizing, my problem here is that `std::for_each` is going to pass me a `std::pair<key,Data>` whereas `Filter::filter` expects a reference to `Data`.

Comment: why didnt you come to the question directly ? :) And why do you think it will be any different than iterating over a vector ?

Comment: Hi ArunMu, sorry for the whole explanation. I just wanted to make sure that I understand how `bind` works (maybe I misunderstood something). Related to your second question, it will be different as now the function object receives a `std::pair` rather than a reference to the next `vector` element.

Comment: Still not clear :(. How does your map look like map<?,?>.

Comment: The map looks like: `std::map<int,Data>` and I want to apply the filter over all the data elements. That is, if I call: 
`std::for_each (sampleMap.begin (),sampleMap.end (),boost::bind (&Filter::filter,filter,_1))`


I get the following error:
`error: no match for call to  (boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Filter, Data&>) (Filter&, std::pair<const int, Data>&)`. 

Now `for_each`is passing a `std::pair` since I am iterating over a map rather than a vector.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311752/boost-bind-to-access-stdmap-elements-in-stdfor-each . Some thing very close to what you want

Comment: Please make your title describe the question rather than just listing technologies. It's useless as it stands.

Comment: Hi ArunMu,thanks for the link, it solved my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
  struct Sample
  {
    int i_;
    double d_;
  };
  typedef std::map<int, Sample> Samples;
  struct Filter
  {
    void filter(const Sample &s)
    {
    }
  };
  Filter filter;
  Samples samples;
  std::for_each(samples.begin(), samples.end(), boost::bind(&Filter::filter, filter, boost::bind(&Samples::value_type::second, _1))); 
}
```

Comment: Hello. 
Is it possible to get   double d_;  from  &Samples::value_type::second ?

Comment: I mean run not through the second but through the fields of the second

Comment: @Max Do you want to iterate through the struct fields? Well, that's unrelated to the original question, but as long as we do not have reflection in c++, you need to use boost::fusion struct adaptor for that. Adapting a struct makes it an iterable fusion sequence. (You'd better open another question.)

Comment: I made solution with lambda) I'll read about fusion and open new question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use `bind()` to iterate over a `std::map<...>`. However, note that the elements in the `std::map<K, V>` have the type `std::pair<K const, V>` i.e. the bound function needs to be cable of accessing objects of this type. That said, I'm not aware that `bind()` alone can be used to transform this argument into the argument you are actually interested (i.e. to a `V`). To do this, you probably need an auxiliary function which is called to do the transformation. If you `bind()` this function as well `bind()` can do a suitable composition, i.e. I think something like this should work:

```
template <typename Result>
struct project2nd {
    typedef Result const& result_type;
    template <typename T>
    result_type operator()(std::pair<T, Result> const& arg) const {
        return arg.second;
    }
};
...
... bind(&Filter::filter, filter, bind(project2nd<Data>(), _1)) ...
```

For `bind()` to work with a funciton object it seems it needs some information about related types: the result of the function call operator can't be deduced but is apparently needed internally. I assume that `bind()` is clever enough to pass references through. Otherwise the type needs to be changed to be `Result`. Also, I don't know if `bind()` also needs to know about the argumen type. If so, the `project2nd` class tmeplate would need to take both types as argument.

Comment: Hi Dietmar, first of all thanks for your response. I have tried your solution an I got some compilation errors:
`/home/anibal/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: no type named ‘result_type’ in ‘struct project2nd’`
...
`error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Filter, Data&>) (Filter&, std::pair<const int, Data>&)’`
...
`error: creating array with negative size (‘-0x00000000000000001’)`

Comment: Er, yes... I didn't have the possibility to test the answer (I still don't have it, for that matter) so I forgot about some of the needs of using `bind()` with function objects. This particular one is a bit annoying as it requires that `result_type` is defined in the function object. This, in turn, means that it can't be deduced from the argument of the function call operator. I'll update the answer with a possible approach to do it. Off-hand, I don't know if there are additional requirements.