# Overloaded Sum Function, Confusing List/Vector with Map

Tags: c++, templates, stl, dictionary, overloading

I'm still working on overloading a Sum function that can work with either vectors/lists or maps. My vector/list version of the sum function works fine, and I think my code for the map version is pretty decent, but when I test it, the compiler seems to think I'm trying to call the list/vector version of the function, and throws some compiler errors. Relevant code is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
const double Sum(typename T start_iter, typename T end_iter)
{// code...
}

template <typename T>
const double Sum(map<typename T, double> start_iter, map<typename T, double> end_iter)
{// different code...
}

int main()
{

map<string, double> test_map; // construct empty map

test_map["Line1"] = 10; // add some data
test_map["Line2"] = 15; 

Sum(test_map.begin(),test_map.end()) // this tries to call the list/vector version of sum
}
```

How am I confusing these functions? Thanks!

Comment: First, you're missing two `::iterator`s in the second declaration. The `typename` in `map<typename T, double>` is also unnecessary. Second, in `map<T, double>::iterator`, `T` is in a non-deducible context, so you're out of luck. You can try to overload based on whether `std::iterator<Iter>::value_type` is a `pair` or not.

Comment: So, it should be more like this?
`const double Sum<map<T,double>>(map<typename T, double>::iterator start_iter, map<typename T, double>::iterator end_iter)`

Comment: @Clark: yes, but also pay attention to what avakar said about deducing T. If you call your function as `Sum(test_map.begin(),test_map.end())`, the compiler cannot work out by template argument deduction that `T` is supposed to be `string`. You could call it as `Sum<string>(test_map.begin(),test_map.end())`.

Comment: Regardless of how you write it, it won't work, because the compiler will not be able to deduce that `T` is a `string` by matching `map<T, double>::iterator` against `map<string, double>::iterator`. That's what is meant by non-deducible context.

Comment: The reason, btw, is that there's nothing in the standard to say whether `map<string,double>::iterator` is the same type as `something_else::iterator`. `iterator` is just a typedef in a class, it's a *name* for a type. Template argument deduction works on the types passed, not on the names for them. "Appears as a typedef in some class" is not a property of a type that the standard pays any attention to.

Comment: If `Sum` only uses the values, then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259240/iterator-adapter-to-iterate-just-the-values-in-a-map. You can make it the caller's problem to pass the right values to `Sum`, rather than `Sum`'s problem to anticipate every container that exists or will exist in future, and know how to get out of it the "right" value to add. You're only special-casing `map` at the moment, but what about `unordered_map`, `multimap` and `unordered_multimap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight alternative to what is being discussed in the comments:

```
template <typename Vt>
struct getter
{
  Vt operator()(const Vt& v)
  {
    return v;
  }
};

template <typename F, typename G>
struct getter<std::pair<F, G> >
{
  G operator()(const std::pair<F, G>& v)
  {
    return v.second;
  }
};


template <typename Iterator>
int sum(Iterator it, Iterator end)
{
  int r = 0;
  for(; it != end; ++it)
    r += getter<typename Iterator::value_type>()(*it);
  return r;
}
```

Now the `sum` function doesn't care what it is iterating over, simply rely on the appropriate `getter` to get the values...

For example:

```
  std::map<int, int> f;
  f[1] = 3;
  f[2] = 6;
  f[3] = 12;
  f[4] = 24;

  std::vector<int> g;
  g.push_back(4);
  g.push_back(8);
  g.push_back(16);
  g.push_back(32);

  std::cout << sum(f.begin(), f.end()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << sum(g.begin(), g.end()) << std::endl;
```

Comment: +1, nice solution that doesn't involve `enable_if` (which is what I'd use :) ).

Comment: Although beware that calling `sum` using iterators to a `vector<pair<int,int>>` now adds up all the second elements. In the questioner's original code it presumably doesn't compile (because the body of `Sum` will try to add elements), and that might be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as explained in the previous remarks, the compiler cannot deduce the container type of the iterator given as the parameter of `Sum`.

However, it is possible to use the fact that `std::map<X,Y>::iterator::value_type` is a pair of values `std::pair<XX, YY>`. Of course, this would not limit the desired specializing of `Sum` to `std::map` iterators, but to any container iterator returning a pair of element (eg. `std::vector< std::pair<std::string, double> >`.)

If this does not bother you, or if sthg like `std::vector< std::pair<std::string, double> >` should use the same specialization, then the following code seems to give the desired results in your case:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/remove_reference.hpp>


// a small structure to 
template <class U>
struct is_a_key_pair_it
{
  typedef boost::false_type type;
};

template <class A, class B>
struct is_a_key_pair_it< std::pair<A, B> >
{
  typedef boost::true_type type;
};

// using boost::disable_if to avoid the following code to be instanciated 
// for iterators returning a std::pair
template <typename T>
const double Sum(T start_iter, T end_iter, 
  typename boost::disable_if<
    typename is_a_key_pair_it<
      typename boost::remove_reference<typename T::value_type>::type 
    >::type >::type * dummy = 0)
{
  // code...
  std::cout << "non specialized" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

// using boost::enable_if to limit the following specializing of Sum
// to iterators returning a std::pair
template <typename T>
const double Sum(T start_iter, T end_iter, 
  typename boost::enable_if<
    typename is_a_key_pair_it<
      typename boost::remove_reference<typename T::value_type>::type 
    >::type >::type * dummy = 0)
{
  // different code...
  std::cout << "specialized" << std::endl;
  return 1;
}




int main()
{
  typedef std::map<std::string, double> map_t;

  // check
  assert(is_a_key_pair_it<map_t::iterator::value_type>::type::value);
  // works also for const_iterators
  assert(is_a_key_pair_it<map_t::const_iterator::value_type>::type::value);

  map_t test_map;
  test_map["Line1"] = 10; // add some data
  test_map["Line2"] = 15; 

  double ret = Sum(test_map.begin(),test_map.end()); 
}
```